# mod_rewrite rule is ignored with Wordpress

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to use mod_rewrite to redirect all requests to a certain directory to a specific page:

```
RewriteEngine On  # Turn on rewriting
RewriteRule /about/(.*) /wp-content/themes/twentyfiteen/test.php
```

From here I plan to get the requested URI and serve up the appropriate page.

But it seems that this rule does not even get triggered.

Thanks

Comment: Post all your rules (including wordpress related).

Comment: Poor title: will edit. This is on its own now. No rules in the apache site definition either. Is this rule valid? I want it triggered on something like http://example.com/about/local-events

Comment: What URL are you attempting to go to?

Answer (score 0):

URI's that are sent through rewrite rules in an htaccess file have the leading slash removed, so you can't match `/about/`, you need to remove the leading slash:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRle ^about/(.*)$ /wp-content/themes/twentyfiteen/test.php [L]
```

Comment: Works, what does [L] do?

Comment: It stops rewriting in the current iteration. So if you have rules after this one, they won't get executed. (`L` = "Last")